# Block pop-ups from embedded iframe | Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, popup

I embeded an iframe on a page but when you click on the frame a pop up appears, I want to block this popups, I know I can do this job with sandbox, but I want to do it with code javascript or php

```
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

And I wanna some code that block all popups redirects in my page

Thanks in advance

Comment: perhaps take a look at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/